# How to integrate following indefinite integal?

Tags: integration, analysis, indefinite-integrals

The integral is

$$
\int\frac{x-\sin x}{1-\cos x} \,dx
$$

However, the only guess I have is that the denominator is the derivative of the numerator. Probably the integration by substitution will work here?

Comment: I have not worked out entirely, but would multiplying both denominator and numerator by $(1+\cos x)$ work?

Comment: try the $1-\cos(x)=2 \sin^2 (\frac{x}{2})$ substitution

Comment: try $1-\cos(x)=2\sin^2(x/2)$ *after* separating into two integrals $\int \frac x{2\sin^2(x/2)}\operatorname d x-\int \frac{\sin x}{1-\cos x}\operatorname d x$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$\begin{align*}
\int\frac{x-\sin x}{1-\cos x}dx
&= \int \frac{(x-\sin x)(1+\cos x)}{(1-\cos x)(1+\cos x)}\ dx \\
&= \int \frac{x + x\cos x - \sin x -\sin x \cos x}{1-\cos^2 x}\ dx\\
&= \int (x\csc ^2 x + x \cot x \csc x - \csc x - \cot x)\ dx\\
&= -\int x\ d(\cot x) - \int x\ d(\csc x) - \int \csc x\ dx - \int \cot x\ dx\\
&= -x \cot x + \int \cot x\ dx - x\csc x + \int \csc x\ dx  - \int \csc x\ dx - \int \cot x\ dx\\
&= -x \cot x - x\csc x + C\\
&= -x(\cot x + \csc x) + C
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Downvoted? Did I make any mistake?

Comment: Apparently there's someone that finds it funny to downvote everything

Comment: Not only is it correct, but it's a nice method to use on this one.